# MySQL: NOT EXISTS vs LEFT OUTER JOIN...IS NULL

Tags: mysql, join, if-not-exists

Is `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN...IS NULL` more efficient for finding records in one table that aren't in another? Specifically, I'm trying to figure out which of the two queries below is better:

```
SELECT table1.id FROM table1 WHERE table1.a='FOO' AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id);
```

or

```
SELECT table1.id FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id WHERE table1.a='FOO' AND table2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Efficiency is similar. Depends on the version of mysql and your specific situation (table sizes, distribution.) I suggest you test both in your application but don't expect to see major differences. More like a 20-30% diff at maximum.

Comment: in addition to @ypercubeᵀᴹ update this will also depend on indexes

Answer (score -3):

**NOT EXISTS** performs in most straightforward way: just checks equality and returns TRUE or FALSE on the first hit / miss.
**LEFT JOIN / IS NULL** either makes an additional table look-up or does not return on the first match and performs more poorly in both cases.