# MySQL - NOT IN ... vs LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to understand in terms of performance which approach is better:

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE col1 NOT IN(SELECT col1 FROM table2)
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
WHERE table2.col1 IS NULL
```

The first query uses `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`,The second uses simply index.

Comment: I guess this is similar to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61521/mysql-not-exists-vs-left-outer-join-is-null

Answer (score 5):

[EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) tells you the difference.

If it shows `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` it means that the subquery in `IN()` is executed once-per-row for the `table1`, that may be really many times if the table is big.

Different MySQL versions may apply different optimizations to the first query to get rid of the `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` or at least minimize its performance impact:

- use subquery cache - may be good if there are many duplicates in `col1` values
- change `NOT IN` into `NOT EXISTS`
- materialize the subquery into a temporary table and (left)join to it
- rewrite the query to left-join directly

If none of these is applied by your optimizer, use the second query because MySQL optimizes joins better (more so in older versions). Having a plan with `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` in it is not effective in most cases.

IIRC the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` may be evaluated as `NOT EXISTS` with specific optimization for that plan.

For both queries you should have an index on `table2.col1` to allow fast execution of the subquery or fast detection of (non) existence of the row.

Comment: I didnt exactly understand, the bullets are your recommendations right? Using not exists changed the execution plan to materialize table2. In your 4th bullet, you mean like my second query right? and can you elaborate about the first bullet - what do you mean by caching the sub query? isnt that materializing?

Comment: @omri The bullet points are different ways ho MySQL can execute your first query - different versions have different optimizations implemented. If your plan says `dependent subquery` then probably none of these is available in your version (for example subquery cache is only in MariaDB afaik, and maybe MySQL 5.7 but the manual is not clear on that). I should clarify that if the first query is NOT optimized by your version, the second query (left join) is generally much better and safer.

Comment: I switched to NOT EXISTS, its execution plan seems good. Isnt it preferred over the second query?

Comment: @omri for the 4th bullet point - some versions can do that rewrite automatically if I recall corectly.

Comment: @omri if you rewrote it right (adding the right condition) then it might be ok - for my version (MariaDB 10) NOT IN and NOT EXISTS are exactly the same - optimizer rewrites both to the same optimized query

Comment: @omri you should benchmark both queries on some nontrivial data and see for yourself. For me the first version uses special `unique_subquery` access type but still it is an dependent subquery (cached), where the left join uses special `Not exists` optimization in explains `Extra` and no subquery.

Comment: I noticed when i run the `NOT EXISTS` on one of our clients with a big db it used materialized on tabl2. But when I tried in my local environment it chose `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`, So `NOT EXISTS` can also act as `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`

Comment: @omri Yes, the optmizer decides from table statistics, for small tables any optimization is usually meaningless, but it tries harder for the big ones. If it does materialization on the big table then that sounds quite good, but still try to compare that to the left join to be sure.

Comment: The left join seems to act the best, also saw this interesting topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null

Comment: @omri nice answer but unfortunately a bit old. There was a lot of work done on the optimizer in the meantime.

Comment: by the way, when you say your version is MariaDB 10, doesnt this optimizations are happening in the engine(like innodb) and not the server

Comment: @omri Afaik no, most SQL-level optimizations are done "above" the engine level. There are some optimizations which can go deeper (`Using index condition` is one of these implemented by the engine) but most should be engine agnostic as they are mostly transformations of the sql query etc.

Comment: I am just more confused :( I am using maria 10.0.17 by the way. I see in mariaDB documentations that they suggest using IN over EXISTS https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/exists-to-in-optimization/

Comment: They do not "suggest" it, they say they internally optimize it that way in some cases. In some other cases they instead do [`IN-to-EXISTS`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/non-semi-join-subquery-optimizations/#the-in-to-exists-transformation). But the `EXISTS-to-IN` allows the [materialization you saw](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/non-semi-join-subquery-optimizations/#materialization-for-non-correlated-in-subqueries) - all this the optimizer decides internally, you do not have to change the original query. Use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED <query>; SHOW WARNINGS;` to see part of optimizer output.